# What is the name of λx.λf.fx (like reverse apply) in lambda calculus? Does the corresponding function have a standard name in programming?

Tags: functional-programming, haskell, lambda

What is the name of λx.λf.fx in lambda calculus?

Does the corresponding function have a standard name in functional programming languages, like Haskell?

In object oriented programming, is there a usual name for a method `foo` which takes a function as an argument, such that `x.foo(f)` returns `f(x)`?

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes. It seems a perfectly reasonable question to me.

Comment: I have posted an answer below but I realised that the OP was asking what is the name of this lambda expression so I deleted =D

Comment: The concept you refer to is known as a combinator, have a read here if you're not familiar http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus though I'm not familiar with a known combinator of the nature you refer to though, C from BCKW is close (it's flip) but *not the same* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,C,K,W_system why not have some fun and come up with the combination of those combinators that results in your function :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the original Alonzo Church's "The calculi of lambda-conversion", he denotes this combinator by *T*.

[In the context of Church numerals, it is called *exp*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Computation_with_Church_numerals).
This matches the "shorthand" notation used by Church for the "application" of a term *N* to a term *M*: "[*M*<sup>*N*</sup>]" stands for "(*NM*)".

I haven't heard yet of a standard name for an analogous function in programming.

Answer (score 10):

In Haskell, `\x.\f.f x` is `flip ($)` which as `$` is read as *apply*, I would read as *reverse apply*.

Roughly based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090168/is-there-an-inverse-of-the-haskell-operator

Comment: This wrong... flip is `\f.\x.\y.f y x` flip is C here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B,C,K,W_system

Comment: also adding `$` to flip like this is expecting a partially applied function that takes over 2 arguments where you're going to only flip the last 2 so you partially apply all but those 2

Comment: So you doubt that `(\f.\x.\y.f y x) (\f.\x.f x)` reduces to `(\x.\f.f x)` modulo renaming? Which it does.

Answer (score 9):

Using the standard [combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic) you can express this function as

```
C I
```

where

```
C f x y = (f y) x
```

In Haskell it would be

```
flip id
```

Here `id`'s type is specialized to `(a -> b) -> a -> b` and `flip` swaps `a -> b` and `a`.

You can also express it in the [SKI calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus):

```
S (K (S I)) K
```

Comment: +1 for deducing the combinators for this. I really don't suspect it's a much known thing, though if as he identified it's something related to church numerals, I'm inclined to wonder if CI is documented anywhere as relevant in anyones church numeral studies

Answer (score 5):

This is sometimes referred to as the *thrush combinator*, and in Clojure it's called the [*thread-first macro*](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E). It's primary use is in allowing you to express a computation as a series of chained computations in the order they execute in. For instance, taking a value `x`, passing it to a function `f`, then passing the results of `f(x)` to a function `g`, would be written as `g(f(x))` using standard function composition (or `g (f x)` if you're working with implicit parentheses.) This can be awkward when there's a large number of chained functions because you have to read them in the reverse order of how they execute. The thrush combinator lets you express this differently, if we define the thrush combinator as:

```
T x f = f x
T x f g ... = T (T x f) g ...
```

Then the expression `T x f g h` becomes `h (g (f x))`.

(For those looking for more information as well as a concrete implementation in the language Racket, I have a blog post on the subject: [Thrush Combinator in Racket](http://codepen.io/Universalist/blog/thrush-combinator-in-racket))

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand your question correctly, but I believe this is known as the (reverse) Pipe Operator in ML languages.

```
[1; 2; 3] |> List.map sq // let it = [1; 4; 9]
```

There is also the Reverse Pipe Operator which helps with order of operations.

```
printf "The value is.." <| 2 + 3 // let it = "The value is..5"
```

This is useful because the unpiped form

```
printf "The value is.." 2 + 3 ;; error
```

would error because printf would try to evaluate `"The value is.." 2` and error because there is no defined `+` operator. In order to make that work, use parenthesis:

```
printf "The value is.." (2 + 3) // let it = "The value is..5"
```

As for practical use, the `|>` operator is incredibly useful and the bread-and-butter of many ML and ML-inspired languages such as F#, LiveScript and Elixir. `<|` is less common and typically only used when it increases readability.